# Switch case with multiple args

Tags: groovy, switch-statement

I have to do a configuration based in some id's, some configurations are the same, for that reason I don't like to make multiple switch for each configuration.

I did something like:

```
 switch (  sportId  ) 
    case [BASEBALL, BASKETBALL]
    //do some configuration
```

If I put each case apart the switch works well, the problen is when i put BASEBALL and BASKETBALL in the same case becasuse the config is the same, this doesn't works.

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: if you use `case BASEBALL:` and `case BASKETBALL:` in two lines this means "either this or that" and there is no reason to "not work" at first glance.  Please add the error your seeing or define what "does not work" mean. We can not guess that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using enums? The following example works for me:

```
enum Sport {
    BASEBALL, BASKETBALL, FOOTBALL, SWIMMING, HOCKEY
}

def set1 = EnumSet.of ( Sport.BASEBALL, Sport.BASKETBALL )
def set2 = EnumSet.of ( Sport.FOOTBALL, Sport.SWIMMING, Sport.HOCKEY )

def sportId = Sport.BASKETBALL

switch ( sportId ) {
    case set1:
        println 'doing basebase & basketball stuff'
        break
    case set2:
        println 'doing football, swimming & hockey stuff'
        break
    default:
        println 'nothing'
}
```